# extract the part of text from the href using bs4

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

want to extract the text from the href, it seem i just can extract whole href from the HTML

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

soup=BeautifulSoup("""<div class="cdAllIn"><a href="/footba/all.aspx?lang=EN&amp;tmatchid=6be0690b-93e3-4300-87e9-7d0aa5797ae0" title="All Odds"><img src="/football/info/images/btn_odds.gif?CV=L302R1g" alt="All Odds" title="All Odds"></a></div>
<div class="cdAllIn"><a href="/footba/all.aspx?lang=EN&amp;tmatchid=6be0690b-93e3-4300-87e9-7d0aa5797ae0" title="All Odds"><img src="/football/info/images/btn_odds.gif?CV=L302R1g" alt="All Odds" title="All Odds"></a></div>
<div class="cdAllIn"><a href="/footba/all.aspx?lang=EN&amp;tmatchid=6be0690b-93e3-4300-87e9-7d0aa5797ae0" title="All Odds"><img src="/football/info/images/btn_odds.gif?CV=L302R1g" alt="All Odds" title="All Odds"></a></div>
<div class="cdAllIn"><a href="/footba/all.aspx?lang=EN&amp;tmatchid=6be0690b-93e3-4300-87e9-7d0aa5797ae0" title="All Odds"><img src="/football/info/images/btn_odds.gif?CV=L302R1g" alt="All Odds" title="All Odds"></a></div>
""",'html.parser')

lines=soup.find_all('a')
for line in lines:
    print(line['href'])
```

Result :

```
/footba/all.aspx?lang=EN&tmatchid=6be0690b-93e3-4300-87e9-7d0aa5797ae0
/footba/all.aspx?lang=EN&tmatchid=6be0690b-93e3-4300-87e9-7d0aa5797ae0
/footba/all.aspx?lang=EN&tmatchid=6be0690b-93e3-4300-87e9-7d0aa5797ae0
/footba/all.aspx?lang=EN&tmatchid=6be0690b-93e3-4300-87e9-7d0aa5797ae0
```

Expected Result :

```
6be0690b-93e3-4300-87e9-7d0aa5797ae0
6be0690b-93e3-4300-87e9-7d0aa5797ae0
6be0690b-93e3-4300-87e9-7d0aa5797ae0
6be0690b-93e3-4300-87e9-7d0aa5797ae0
```

Comment: Why would that be the expected result? `...['href']` gets the values of the href attributes, as expected. Desired perhaps?

Comment: dear, yes, just try to write a code for linking with the result ! sorry for my fault

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Split the string using `=` and grab the last index.

```
for line in lines:
    print(line['href'].split('=')[-1])
```

Hope this helps! Cheers!

Answer (score 2):

Since you need to only retrieve the tmatchid value, find the substring tmatchid= in the url and extract the remaining url from that index

```
lines=soup.find_all('a')
for line in lines:
    index=line['href'].find('tmatchid=')+9
    print(line['href'][index:])
```

Output

> 6be0690b-93e3-4300-87e9-7d0aa5797ae0
>   6be0690b-93e3-4300-87e9-7d0aa5797ae0
>   6be0690b-93e3-4300-87e9-7d0aa5797ae0
>   6be0690b-93e3-4300-87e9-7d0aa5797ae0